# sample_weight_mode Input Dimention problem in Unet

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning

When I train,I got this error message

```
main.py
train_history=model.fit_generator(myGene,steps_per_epoch=200,epochs=20,callbacks=[model_checkpoint])

error message
發生例外狀況: ValueError
Found a sample_weight array with shape (1, 512, 3072, 1). In order to use timestep-wise sample weighting, you should pass a 2D sample_weight array.
  File "C:\Labbb\unet_mao0\main.py", line 88, in <module>
    train_history=model.fit_generator(myGene,steps_per_epoch=200,epochs=20,callbacks=[model_checkpoint])
ValueError: Found a sample_weight array with shape (1, 512, 3072, 1). In order to use timestep-wise sample weighting, you should pass a 2D sample_weight array.
```

It ask me input 1D or 2D sample_weight_array

```
model.py
model.compile(sample_weight_mode='temporal', optimizer=Adam(lr=1e-4), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I try to fix this problem in data.py

```
origin data.py
        y_binary = to_categorical(y_int)  # Convert integer labels to binary vectors
        yield (img_batch, y_binary, mask_batch)
```

I let this array be an 2D array but now it ask me input 4D now

```
data.py
        y_binary = to_categorical(y_int)  
        y_binary = y_binary.reshape(y_binary.shape[:2])
        yield (y_binary)
```

```
error message
發生例外狀況: ValueError
Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (512, 3072)
  File "C:\Labbb\unet_mao0\main.py", line 88, in <module>
    train_history=model.fit_generator(myGene,steps_per_epoch=200,epochs=20,callbacks=[model_checkpoint])
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (512, 3072)
```